BigQuery Dataform Set Upstream Table Dependency
I am trying to use Dataform to create two BigQuery tables, table1 and table2, in a BigQuery dataset SILVER. My directory structure looks like this:
definitions
├── source
│   └── table1_raw.sqlx
└── silver
    ├── table1_stg.sqlx
    └── table2_stg.sqlx

table2_stg.sqlx is referencing table1_stg using FROM ${ref("table1_stg")}, however, I am receiving a compilation error Not found: table PROJECT:SILVER.table1_stg was not found in location us-east1.
How can I ensure that table1_stg.sqlx runs before table2_stg.sqlx to prevent the downstream dependency error?
I have tried both using resolve() instead of ref() and declaring the upstream table explicitly in the config like
config {
  type: "table",
  name: "table2_stg",
  dependencies: ["table1_stg"]
}
...

but receive the same error.
I'm aware it's possible to create a referenceable_output_table from standard SQL using type: "operations", however, this seems to defeat the purpose of using type: "table".

Your configuration and looks fine but dependencies won't be run when compiling, they will only be run as part of a manual execution or a workflow execution.  Recall that the compilation step is just building a SQL query for you based on the .sqlx specification (SQL+JS). That query still needs to be executed. See here for manually executing a file.
To fix the compilation error you would need to execute the table1_stg.sqlx query so that it is actually materialized in BigQuery.
In the future when executing the table2_stg.sqlx query you can elect to "include dependencies" if running manually or within a workflow.
